# S-matrix branch cuts properties

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, s-matrix-theory

I'm trying to formally understand some non-perturbative results in scattering theory but the material available on the topic are not too friendly, so there are some very simple and essential facts I fail to fully comprehend. Regarding the branch cuts arising from particle creation thresholds:

***(i)*** Why are the cuts necessarily in the real line? That is, why can't we choose an arbitrary curve starting at $s=M^2$ and ending at infinity?

***(ii)*** A generality I've heard some times is that the branch cuts arising in the S-matrix are always that of a logarithm or of a square root. Why is this the case? Any formal (enough) derivation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: (i) as with any branch cut, you can move it around*, but there are many thresholds; the first one is two-particle at $4m^2$, but there are $n$-particle ones. They have their own cuts. *provided that you can analytically continue under the cut, which is not obvious -- not sure what is known about this.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk So, assuming we don't cross any singularity, as we always can, we could move the branch cuts around? To any side of the real axis?

Comment: Branch cuts are not real -- they are just a way of depicting a function on the plane, when the function has to be defined on a more complicated Riemann surface. So yes, you can move them around to "uncover" other branches of the function. However, there can be singularities on these other branches, and potentially there could be dense lines of singularities beyond which the function can not be analytically continued (for example as in [Dedekind eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function)). I am not sure what is known about S matrix in this context.